# Can't run project in Eclipse imported from Git

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, github, egit

I have a project in my Eclipse workspace from Github (via File -> Import -> Projects from GIT).
However, I am unable to run the example because the only option I have under "Run As" is "Run Configurations."

After going to "Run Configurations" I click "browse" and the project that I imported from GIT isn't there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Best thing to do is to clone the repository and manually import it to eclipse, like it wasn't a git project, and egit would identify as one after you have imported

Comment: Will give that a try. When I manually import, should I use the "projects from GIT" or "remote file system" option?

Comment: first thing you should do is clone the project locally from your terminal(*nix) or via a git tool(windows/cmd prompt), then 
File -> Import -> General -> Import existing projects into workspace

if it is a maven project:

File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven projects

Comment: Ended up working when I imported it as a maven projects. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

The question is already answered in the comments but I am providing this answer to possibly clear up some misunderstandings.

In order to recognize a folder as a (Java) project, Eclipse needs to read (or create) a few files for each project, like .project and .classpath. If you do not have them in your project, or do no create them during the import, then Eclipse just imports it as a resource, or a dumb folder.

If your project is tracked by git and is also a maven project, you can clone it locally with Git (command line or GUI tool) and then "Import as existing Maven project" in Eclipse. This will use your pom.xml to create the two files mentioned above and your project will be buildable.

Alternatively, if you have already imported it as you described in your question, you can right click on your project on Package Explorer and choose Configure-->Convert to Maven Project. This will create the .project and allow you to build the project using Maven (right click->Run as..-> Maven build) and Eclipse's incremental builder (where necessary). If your maven project builds an executable, the option to execute it will also be available in the Run as.. menu.

If you have a more complex maven project (like an aggregate pom), and want a Run Configuration that runs a specific program, you will have to write it yourself by opening the Run Configurations window and explicitly referencing the java class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't import the project using `git clone`. Download it as zip file and extract it. Add it using `Project>import> General> Projects` from folder and Archive.
Provide path of extracted folder into import source and finish and go to eclipse and clean and build safely run and right click on project and run it.
It should work