# Eclipse Luna - Run Configurations won't display my git Project

Tags: eclipse, git

Recently I pulled a project form Github. The language I'm working with is C. When I try to run it, it will say "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches." I can't compile either. So what I did was search the internet for how to fix this. And the mighty internet said I shall change my run configurations and select my project and then run that. This is what I tried - I opened the configurator and browsed for my project, but it wasn't displayed. I can see the project in the navigator and I can commit/push/pull as well. Still, I can't choose it in the run configurator. Any ideas what I could do?

Thank you very much!

PS: I already saw this post ([Can't run project in Eclipse imported from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207672/cant-run-project-in-eclipse-imported-from-git)) but there is no maven option when importing.

Comment: Do you have CDT installed on top of eclipse platform?

Comment: I guess. I downloaded this version http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunasr2

Comment: Do you have an file with the ending ".launch" inside your project in GitHub?
This is the file which Eclipse is using to store the launch configurations so that they can be added to GitHub or other versioning control systems.

Comment: actually no - is this just an empty file?

Comment: Launches are stored for a Workspace, not a project. They are in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/`. So they are probably not included into the Git repo that you've cloned. This is why I dislike Eclipse. :)